# Jupyter Notebook to HTML - Notebook JSON is invalid: ['outputPrepend']

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to convert my Jupyter Notebook file (.ipynb) into an HTML file for easier reading. Every time I try to save the notebook I get a "Notebook validation failed" error:

```
Notebook validation failed: ['outputPrepend', 'outputPrepend', 'outputPrepend', 'outputPrepend', 'outputPrepend', 'outputPrepend', 'outputPrepend', 'outputPrepend', 'outputPrepend', 'outputPrepend', 'outputPrepend', 'outputPrepend'] has non-unique elements:
[
 "outputPrepend",
 "outputPrepend",
 "outputPrepend",
 "outputPrepend",
 "outputPrepend",
 "outputPrepend",
 "outputPrepend",
 "outputPrepend",
 "outputPrepend",
 "outputPrepend",
 "outputPrepend",
 "outputPrepend"
]
```

[message when file is saved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dO27.png)

When I try to download as .html using File > Download as, I get a further more detailed error but I still cannot make out what it means or what needs to be done to solve the problem and finally download as HTML:

```
nbconvert failed: ['outputPrepend', 'outputPrepend', 'outputPrepend', 'outputPrepend', 'outputPrepend', 'outputPrepend', 'outputPrepend', 'outputPrepend', 'outputPrepend', 'outputPrepend', 'outputPrepend', 'outputPrepend'] has non-unique elements

Failed validating 'uniqueItems' in code_cell['properties']['metadata']['properties']['tags']:

On instance['cells'][70]['metadata']['tags']:
['outputPrepend',
 'outputPrepend',
 'outputPrepend',
 'outputPrepend',
 'outputPrepend',
 'outputPrepend',
 'outputPrepend',
 'outputPrepend',
 'outputPrepend',
 'outputPrepend',
 'outputPrepend',
 'outputPrepend']
```

[message when trying to download as HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJenV.png)

This is only happening on the specific notebook I am working on. I have tried to save and export other notebooks as HTML successfully.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Could you inline your error messages from the screenshots the into the question?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Willie. Question has been edited to include to inline the error messages.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I recently experienced this from using the VSCode Notebook editor. I solved it by opening the notebook in a regular text editor and deleting all the extra `outputPrepend`-items, leaving only a single one in each array.

Comment: Incredible, Jacob. I followed your advice, opened the .ipynb file in Notepad and simply deleted extra `outputPrepend` items. This has done it and I can now download the file to HTML from Jupyter Notebook